# Angular app not working with one component and inject service

Tags: angular

I created simple angular 2 app with one component and inject services 
with return static data but application not work and fire console errors

[code on plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/LthNJTsjCb2ZY43D)

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersServices{
    getUsers():User[] {
        return [{name:'Ahmed'},{name:'Ali'}];
    }
}

@Component({
    selector:'users',
    templateUrl:'./users.component.html',
    providers:[UsersServices]
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit{
    Users:User[];
    constructor(private userService: UsersServices) { }
    ngOnInit(){
         this.Users= this.userService.getUsers();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be an issue in your plnkr https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmb2tu

Comment: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/yjOEVqlYY8GyoqUM?preview

Comment: please can you tell what's errors?

Comment: Look at `tsconfig.json`. I've added one line there. Also I changed `templateUrl` path